# Firebase nested base object

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to use polymorphis with Firebase database?

Let's say that we have data like that:

```
players : {
     "player1" : {
          "name" : "BigJohn",
          "pet" : {
               "name" : "LittleDog",
               "age" : 5
          } 
     }, 
     "player2" : {
          "name" : "FunnyAndrew",
          "pet" : {
               "name" : "DuckDuck",
               "sharp_beak" : true
          }
     }
}
```

We would change it into JavaBeans like this:

```
class Player {
      String name;
      Pet pet;
}

class Pet {
      String name;
}

class Dog extends Pet {
      int age;
}

class Duck extends Pet {
      boolean sharpBeak;
}
```

Is it possible to achieve something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Just push your object with a `setValue` method and Firebase will upload it as a JSON tree:

```
public class User {

public String username;
public String email;
public Account account;

public User() {
    // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
}

public User(String username, String email, Account account) {
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.account = account
}

}
```

And write it with:

```
private void writeNewUser(String userId, String name, String email) {
User user = new User(name, email);

mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
}
```

If you want to update specific fields you will need to use the method `updatechildren` and use a library as GSON or jackson to wrap your custom objects in Json trees:

```
  HashMap<String, Object> updatedUserData = new HashMap<>();

                updatedUserData.put(PostsRepositoryImpl.this.getPeoplePath() + author.getUid() + "/" + Constants.FIREBASE_POST_PATH
                        + newPostKey, true);
                updatedUserData.put(PostsRepositoryImpl.this.getPostsPath() + groupKey + "/" + newPostKey,
                        new ObjectMapper().convertValue(newPost, Map.class));
                databaseReference.updateChildren(updatedUserData)
```

Hope that it will help you!

Comment: What about reading data, it will convert Player.pet to Dog or Duck? Please follow my example, because in your example there is no polymorphism

Comment: My object User have another object "account" inside. To read data you can just call: dataSnapshot.getValue(YourCustomObject.class)

Comment: You can read about it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking into this for myself and I don't believe it is possible right out of the box, you might be able to do some hack-ish things and encapsulate it all in a way it does not seems so ugly, but I'm sure there are better ways to do that. I'm just not willing to dig more into this right now. **As a workaround** I thought about two options:

First: You could get all the data as a json and use Jackson (which firebase also uses under the hood) for parsing and watch for the exceptions

```
private TestParent getObjTestFromDataSnapshot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) throws NotATestObjInstanceException {
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String,Object>> indicator = new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Object>>() {};
  try {
      return mapper.convertValue(dataSnapshot.getValue(indicator), TestChild1.class);
  } catch (UnrecognizedPropertyException e){
    //ignore exception?
  }
  try {
      return mapper.convertValue(dataSnapshot.getValue(indicator), TestChild2.class);
  } catch (UnrecognizedPropertyException e){
    //ignore exception?
  }
  thrown new NotATestObjInstanceException();
}
```

Second: It kinda defeat the polymorphism idea, and I'm not sure if it would be useful in your case, but you could store it in different branchs. pet->dogs, pet->cats, pet->etc